# Titanium (iPhone) login redirect problems

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

I'm having problems with my login redirect.  This is the function that gets fired in app.js on a successful login (the alert works, so I know I'm getting this far).

```
// Once login is finished, grant user inside access:
Ti.App.addEventListener('loginUser', function(event)  
{
    alert("Logged in.");
    home.title = "Logged In";
    home.url = 'main_windows/home_logged_in.js';
    tabGroup.window = home;
});
```

Theoretically, if I change home.url the home tab should redirect to the home_logged_in.js rather than the default home_logged_out.js.

Here's the code that defines home:

```
// Create tabs + page
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();  

var home = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Home',  
    url:'main_windows/home_logged_out.js',
    color:'#fff',
    barColor:'#000'
});  

var homeTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:"Home",
    icon:'images/home-tab.png',
    window:home  
});
```

When I alert(home.url) before the function I get home_loged_out.js, and when I alert after I get home_logged_in.js - but it doesn't change the actual link in the tab.  Anyone have any idea what's going on??  Or have another suggestion for handling successful logins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like there needs to be more code for us to see, but shouldn't home.open() be run again after the url is changed to update it?

Comment: Hi GetFresh, what code would you like to see?  I'll try that home.open solution!  I also added a small bounty to thank you for helping me out!